# Scala case classes inheritance with JSON

Tags: scala, types, case-class, spray-json

In my scenario, I have a bunch of different case-classes which are all inheriting a common trait. Those case classes are to be serialized/deserialized to/from JSON, where I use the spray-json library (which should be of no importance for this question though).

The problem is that each case class of course requires its own (de-)serialization, but at the same time I also want a (de-)serialization for the trait in use. Currently, the approach I'm using is pretty much identical to the one described in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jrudolph/f2d0825aac74ed81c92a , however if you were to expand this to more case classes, this would become quite a lot of 'copy paste pattern'. So my question would be if there is a way to define the read/write for the trait format without having to rely on pattern matchings where all cases do basically the same..

Comment: This cannot be done - Scala implicit are very strict on diverging and cannot be dynamically searched at runtime. All implicits must be resolved at compile time. In your case, you subclass Dog/Cat/... must be explicitly returned as Scala does not know what the actual type of Animal is at compile time.

Comment: @texasbruce Thanks. I feared that this is the case, especially since I have to resolve implicits in this scenario.. but I had hope that I was just too blind to figure out a way around it.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/driver-oss/spray-json-derivation) is a project which uses the [magnila](https://github.com/propensive/magnolia) library to derive Spray-JSON formats for ADTs. But it is not updated for using with latest Scala and Scala.js versions.